# SwipeRefreshLayout not working inside NavigationView's app:headerLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, navigationview

Can someone help with this. I am trying to implement a menu with dynamic content in a `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView` is working fine but the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is not.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Update:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Settings the layout in NavigationView's app:headerLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_navigationview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_home_header"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        .../>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

- You don't need another parent layout `ConstraintLayout`. Because you have no more child, use `SwipeRefreshLayout` directly
- Giving height 1000 is redundant you can just set it to `match_parent`

**Suggestion:**

If you are new to Android, start learning from `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` & `FrameLayout`. That will clear you layouts.

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: I am using it in NavigationView's app:headerLayout

Comment: Are you setting this RecyclerView inside headerLayout?

Comment: No, I am using it inside SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: You are not clear, can you add all related code to your question?

Comment: Any help. @Khemraj

Comment: What is problem with your Swipe Layout, does this not swipe?

Comment: That is the problem. I don't get the throbber that swiperefreshlayout has when you pull it down.